# parsing text file into pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

i have a text file with continuous data.
The following text file contains 2 lines
Example:

```
123@#{} 456@$%
1 23
```

Also, I have column lengths given as 2,3,4 for 3 columns that i need in my data frame. I want to parse the file into a pandas data frame such that the first column gets the first 2 letters, the second column gets the next 3 letters and so on as per the column lengths given (2,3,4).. the next set of letters should form the next row and so on... 
so my pandas data frame should look like:

```
colA    colB       colC
12       3@#       {} 4    
56       @$%       1 23
```

Can anyone suggest something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a built in method to do this, so what I'd do is parse and split the lines and append to a list based on your entire row length:

```
In [216]:

t = '123@#{} 456@$%1 23'
l = [t[x:x+9] for x in range(len(t))[::9]]
l
Out[216]:
['123@#{} 4', '56@$%1 23']
In [218]:
# constuct a df
df = pd.DataFrame({'data':l})
df
Out[218]:
        data
0  123@#{} 4
1  56@$%1 23
In [220]:
# now call the vectorised str methods to split the text data into 3 columns
df['colA'] = df.data.str[0:2]
df['colB'] = df.data.str[2:5]
df['colC'] = df.data.str[5:9]
df
Out[220]:
        data colA colB  colC
0  123@#{} 4   12  3@#  {} 4
1  56@$%1 23   56  @$%  1 23
In [221]:
# drop the data column
df = df.drop('data', axis=1)
df
Out[221]:
  colA colB  colC
0   12  3@#  {} 4
1   56  @$%  1 23
```

**EDIT**

To handle your updated data file I've added some code to parse your text file to populate a dict:

```
In [35]:

d={'data':[]}
line_len=9
skip=True
with open(r'c:\data\date.csv') as f:
    temp = ''
    for line in f:
        if len(line) == 0:
            pass
        if len(line) >= 9:
            d['data'].append(line[:line_len])
        # consume the rest of the line
        if len(temp) !=line_len:
            if len(line) >= 9:
                temp = line[line_len:].rstrip('\n')
            else:
                temp += line.rstrip('\n') 
        if len(temp) == line_len:
            d['data'].append(temp)
            temp=''

    df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df['colA'] = df.data.str[0:2]
df['colB'] = df.data.str[2:5]
df['colC'] = df.data.str[5:9]
df = df.drop('data', axis=1)
df
Out[35]:
  colA colB  colC
0   12  3@#  {} 4
1   56  @$%  1 23
2   12  3@#  {} 4
3   56  @$%  1 23
```

Comment: Hey.. what do you think about pd.read_fwf also mentioned in the answer below. When i directly use df = pd.read_fwf(filename, colspecs=[(0,2), (2,5), (5,9)], header=None)... i can read only one row.

Comment: It's a more compact answer but both answers rely on how the data is read in, so if you read it in as a single line then I think both answers should work

Comment: my file contains thousands of rows... about 2 and a half rows are present in one line of the file. The next line contains the other 2 and a half rows and so on... unless i have each line in my file to have only one row, I can't do a pd.read_fwf(). let me know if you have a solution to this..

Comment: Can you post a few lines then, it sounds like you have embedded new line characters in your file which is different to what you originally posted

Comment: I Have edited my question.... let me know if you have a way around it.. thanks in advance

Comment: Check my updated answer, I tested with multiple lines, so it should be ok, it relies on the data being uniform in their lengths

Answer (score 1):

Split the line into equal-sized parts and use [read_fwf](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_fwf.html):

```
lines = [data[i:i+row_length]  for i in xrange(0, len(data), row_length)]
buf = StringIO.StringIO("\n".join(lines))
df = pd.read_fwf(buf, colspecs=[(0,2), (2,5), (5,9)], header=None)
print df
```

The result will be:

```
    0    1     2
0  12  3@#  {} 4
1  56  @$%  1 23
```

But I think, that the direct approach without pandas would be easier.

Comment: how do i get the data from my file into the variable "data"? should i use pd.read_csv ?

Comment: my file contains thousands of rows... about 2 and a half rows are present in one line of the file. The next line contains the other 2 and a half rows and so on... unless i have each line in my file to have only one row, I can't do a pd.read_fwf(). let me know if you have a solution to this.