# parse continous text file just containing lines into pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a text file containing repeating lines and I want to convert into a dataframe.

```
10/21/2019
abcdef
100.00
10/22/2019
ghijk
120.00
```

There is an obvious pattern and I'd like the dataframe to look like this:

```
Data       | Description | Amount
10/21/2019 | abcdef      | 100.00
10/22/2019 | ghijk       | 120.00
```

How is this done?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the txt file format always ```Date\nDescription\nAmount```?

Comment: please check out this website.
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28836172/parsing-text-file-into-pandas-dataframe/28837075#28837075](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28836172/parsing-text-file-into-pandas-dataframe/28837075#28837075)

Comment: please checkout this website.[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62231215/parse-continous-text-file-just-containing-lines-into-pandas-dataframe#autocomment110062675)

Comment: @Ch3steR that's example only and quite simplified but yes, in the real file the sequence is pretty regular.

Comment: @progamer2020 thanks I'll check them out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read raw data from a file to a `Series` and convert to `PandasArray` to simplify dealing with indices later:

```
raw_data = pd.read_csv("path\to\a\data\file.txt", names=['raw_data'], squeeze=True).array
```

Create a `DataFrame` using slicing:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'Data': raw_data[::3], 'Description': raw_data[1::3], 'Amount': raw_data[2::3]})
```

Just 2 simple steps without regexes and unnecessary transformations. Short and efficient.

Comment: Thanks @wombatonfire. I tried. I get "arrays must all be same length" error. investigating now.

Comment: "arrays must all be same length" means that you have unequal number of records for Data/Description/Amount. Check your raw data, something is missing there. The format of the file that you mentioned in your question means that the number of lines should be devided by 3 without a remainder. That's how you get 3 equal length columns.

Comment: You can check what records are missing with `len(raw_data[::3])` for Data `len(raw_data[1::3])` for Description and `len(raw_data[2::3])` for Amount.

Comment: this solution is really elegant @wombatonfire . Sorry I have not looked at this for such a long time now but I encountered a use case and referred to this solution. So that's why. I am using this but I am stuck a real world problem when data is not always clean with cleanly divisible lines. Most of time there is some sort of inconsistency, ie a missing line or 2 which would result in missing records. How would you handle such cases? thanks

Comment: I would probably try to use `numpy.pad()` on the array to get the necessary shape.

Answer (score 4):

A bit of regex to pull out the details, then forward fill on the first two columns and remove the nulls

```
pattern = r"(?P<Date>\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})|(?P<Description>[a-z]+)|(?P<Amount>\d{1,}\.00)"

res = (df1.text.str.extract(pattern)
       .assign(Date = lambda x: x.Date.ffill(),
               Description = lambda x: x.Description.ffill()
              )
       .dropna(how='any')
      )

res


     Date   Description Amount
2   10/21/2019  abcdef  100.00
5   10/22/2019  ghijk   120.00
```

If you don't care about regex, and the format is constant, then we can reshape the data with numpy and create a new dataframe.

```
#reshape the data
#thanks to @Chester 
#removes unnecessary computation
res = np.reshape(df1.to_numpy(),(-1,3))


#create new dataframe
pd.DataFrame(res,columns=['Date','Description','Amount'])

       Date Description Amount
0   10/21/2019  abcdef  100.00
1   10/22/2019  ghijk   120.00
```

Comment: Such a dirty hack

Comment: so true. removes the need for unnecessary computation. thanks

Comment: i had to read the docs again, to pick out the notes on -1. thanks again.

Comment: @sammywemmy No problem.  Glad to have helped. ;) Nice answer. +1

Answer (score 3):

You can use following code if your string has exact pattern you mentioned

```
string = '''10/21/2019
abcdef
100.00
10/22/2019
ghijk
120.00'''

token_list = string.split()

Data = token_list[0::3]
Description = token_list[1::3]
Amount = token_list[2::3]

Aggregate = list(zip(Data, Description, Amount))
df = pd.DataFrame(Aggregate, columns = ['Data ', 'Description', 'Amount'])
```